# Load image to pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am a newbie to analyze Images using Apache Pig.
Can anyone suggest me how to load and process the images??

I know for textfiles,

```
alias = load '/user/Pavan/sample.txt' using PigStorage(" ");
```

How to do with images??

Comment: What representation of image do you expect in form of Pig tuples? What kind of analysis do you want to perform?

Comment: I need to load the image to an alias.. Can it be possible?

Comment: I don't think Pig is used for image aliasing.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..Then how do we analyze the image format files in Hadoop?? I mean storing the images in hadoop and analyzing them..

Comment: @Dmitry I don't think OP is referring to [image aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing), but rather storing an image to an alias, i.e., a variable in Pig.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, which really depend on the kind of manipulation you're looking to do:

#### 1) Write a custom load function

[Pig can be used for images](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigOverview#Examples), but you'd need to write a [custom load function](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch11.html), which could be more than you're looking to do.

#### 2) Use a Sequence File (my recommendation)

You could also [convert the image to a Sequence File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546040/store-images-videos-into-hadoop-hdfs), which Pig has a loader file for, [available in the Piggybank JAR](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/SequenceFileLoader.html). There are also load functions and store functions for reading and writing Sequence Files available via [Twitter's Elephant Bird package](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird).

[Here's an article about using Sequence Files on Hadoop for astronomical categorization tasks.](http://escience.washington.edu/get-help-now/astronomical-image-processing-hadoop#!)

#### 3) Go with MapReduce.

Depending on the nature of your task, you may be better off in native MapReduce.

Comment: It seems Piggybank's SequenceFileLoader is not for real production. http://grokbase.com/t/pig/user/109vvtx2mc/byteswriteable-support-in-piggybank-sequencefileloader