# How to store jpg files in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

If i have a huge collection of `jpg files` (each folder has `date` as `name of folder`)

**Each around 6-8MB** and in **total around 10-12GB**.

What would be the **best way to store them in HDFS using Java?**

Comment: Please go through the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546040/store-images-videos-into-hadoop-hdfs

Comment: Thanks rahul, this helps. I got the direction atleast..