# Adding image to hdfs in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

My data is in the format of csv file (sam,1,34,there,hello). I want to add an image to each row in the csv file using hadoop. Does any body have any idea about it. I have seen about Hipi which process the image files and adds it also. But I want to add as a column to csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use CSV file, consider using Base64 encoding over binary image data - it will give you a printable string. But in general I would recommend you to switch to sequence file, there you would be able to store the image directly in a binary format

Comment: Any example do you have?

Comment: Here's an example for Base64: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226046/java-convert-image-to-base64

Comment: Here's an example with sequence file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546040/store-images-videos-into-hadoop-hdfs